# Canvas drawing is offset with correct attribute setting

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm following [a tutorial](http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/) for making a simple canvas.

It is almost working but the sketch is offset (arrow is cursor position):

[image]

I've made sure my height and width attributes are being set rather than the style but I still don't kow what's going on.

Code below:

```
document.write ( `
<div class='container' style='padding-top: 20px'>
    <div class='card'>
        <div class='card-body' style='text-align: center;'>
            <canvas id="doodleCanvas" width="280" height="280" style="border:1px solid black;"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
`);

function setupCanvas()
{
    var context = document.getElementById('doodleCanvas').getContext("2d");

    $('#doodleCanvas').mousedown(function(e){
      var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
      var mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

      paint = true;
      addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
      redraw();
    });


    $('#doodleCanvas').mousemove(function(e){
      if(paint){
        addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop, true);
        redraw();
      }
    });

    $('#doodleCanvas').mouseup(function(e){
      paint = false;
    });

    $('#doodleCanvas').mouseleave(function(e){
      paint = false;
    });

    var clickX = new Array();
    var clickY = new Array();
    var clickDrag = new Array();
    var paint;

    function addClick(x, y, dragging)
    {
      clickX.push(x);
      clickY.push(y);
      clickDrag.push(dragging);
    }

    function redraw(){
      context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); // Clears the canvas

      context.strokeStyle = "#df4b26";
      context.lineJoin = "round";
      context.lineWidth = 5;

      for(var i=0; i < clickX.length; i++) {        
        context.beginPath();
        if(clickDrag[i] && i){
          context.moveTo(clickX[i-1], clickY[i-1]);
         }else{
           context.moveTo(clickX[i]-1, clickY[i]);
         }
         context.lineTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
         context.closePath();
         context.stroke();
      }
    }
}

setupCanvas();
```

Any help is appreciated!

**Update**

Just figured that something to do with the bootstrap card is causing it to be offset...

Comment: *"Just figured that..."*: do you still have a question, or are you going to delete it?

Comment: Please provide the CSS style definitions also.

Comment: Hey - the question still stands, the bootstrap card / card body seems to be doing something to offset the drawing...

Comment: The styles are the standard bootstrap styles for card:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the `position: relative` that is in the CSS class definition of `card`. This means that `this.offsetLeft` and `this.offsetTop` are not given with respect to the viewport, but to the `card` element (and thus give smaller values than expected).

You can get the right coordinates by using [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect):

```
$('#doodleCanvas').mousedown(function(e){
  var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
  var mouseX = e.pageX - rect.left;
  var mouseY = e.pageY - rect.top;

  paint = true;
  addClick(e.pageX - rect.left, e.pageY - rect.top);
  redraw();
});


$('#doodleCanvas').mousemove(function(e){
  if(paint){
    var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    addClick(e.pageX - rect.left, e.pageY - rect.top, true);
    redraw();
  }
});
```